# how to pass value of position from one class to another

Tags: android

i want to pass the value of "position" from this class:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.full_image);

    // get intent data
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // Selected image id
  int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");

    // passing array index

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    viewPager.setBackgroundResource(0);
    SlideImage adapter = new SlideImage(this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    } 
    }
```

to this class:

```
public class SlideImage extends PagerAdapter {
Context context;


private int[] GalImages = { R.drawable.ppdt1, R.drawable.ppdt2,
        R.drawable.ppdt3, R.drawable.ppdt4, R.drawable.ppdt5,
        R.drawable.ppdt6, R.drawable.ppdt7, };


SlideImage(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return GalImages.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((ImageView) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
    int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.activity_vertical_margin);
    imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);


    imageView.setImageResource(GalImages[position]);
    ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
    return imageView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
}
  }
```

i want to use the value of position from first class in this method of second class:

```
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
    int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.activity_vertical_margin);
    imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);


    imageView.setImageResource(GalImages[position]);
    ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
    return imageView;
}
```

Please tell me how to pass the value. i tried with intent but not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are only sending the int once. Meaning, if you change

```
SlideImage(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}
```

to

```
private int position;
SlideImage(Context context, int position) {
    this.context = context;
    this.position = position;
}
```

and just make your function load the position variable, it should work.

Sorry if I'm misunderstanding; I've never specifically worked with a PagerAdapter but I've used other adapters and that worked for sending data.

Comment: well.. it is working but now there is another problem. the same image keeps coming on sliding left or right. will troubleshoot it. anyways thanks for your help.

Comment: @user3190368 No problem! Good luck figuring out the sliding.